# Assigning values to a grid cell based on number of intersecting features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, intersection, vector-grid

I need to create a grid that will include a single value for each cell which represents the total number of "stressors" intersecting that cell. So, the final product will be a 1km grid with cells whose values will range from 0 to n (total intersections). Does anyone know of the best way to accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the spatial [join tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000). You need to select the JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE option. Of course, you might have to run this tool several times if your stressors are not in the same feature class (or you first merge them if they are all of the same type)

> JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE —If multiple join features are found that have the
>   same spatial relationship with a single target feature, the attributes
>   from the multiple join features will be aggregated using a field map
>   merge rule. For example, if a point target feature is found within two
>   separate polygon join features, the attributes from the two polygons
>   will be aggregated before being transferred to the output point
>   feature class. If one polygon has an attribute value of 3 and the
>   other has a value of 7, and a Sum merge rule is specified, the
>   aggregated value in the output feature class will be 10. The
>   JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE option is the default.